# Как изменять и добавлять экзепляр класса в Python?

Tags: python-3.x

У меня есть класс. Для демонстрации его работы я создаю экземпляры, в которых есть имя и две оценки. Как сделать так, чтобы данные для нового экземпляра можно было вводить с клавиатура с помощью метода класса, а не писать что-то вроде этого:

`stud3 = Test(input('Введите имя: '), input('Первая оценка: '), input('Вторая оценка: '))`

И каким способом можно реализовать замену атрибутов экземпляра (в данном случае замена оценок у студентов, а нужный экземпляр должен находится по имени).
Вот пока мой тестовый код

```
class Test():

    stud_count = 0 
    instances = {}

    def __init__(self, name, geom, algebra):
        self.name = name
        self.geom = geom
        self.algebra = algebra
        Test.instances[self.name] = self
        Test.stud_count += 1
        print('Добавление студента {}'.format(self.name))
        print('Оценки за экзамены - Геометрия:{} ,Алгебра: {}'.format(self.geom, self.algebra)) 

    def search():
        n = input("Введите имя студента: ")
        if n in Test.instances:
            print('Оценки за экзамены: ', Test.instances[n])
        else:
            print('Не найдено')

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Геометрия - {}, Алгебра - {}".format(
            self.geom,
            self.algebra)

    def howMany():
        if Test.stud_count == 0:
            print('В ведомости нет студентов.')
        else:
            print('Всего студентов: %d' % Test.stud_count)   

Test.howMany()
stud1 = Test("Даша", 5, 5)

Test.howMany()
stud2 = Test("Кристина", 3, 3)

Test.howMany()
stud3 = Test(input('Введите имя: '),
            input('Первая оценка: '),
            input('Вторая оценка: '))

Test.howMany()

Test.search()

n = input("Введите имя студента: ")
if n in Test.instances:
     print('Оценки за экзамены: ', Test.instances[n])
else:
     print('Не найдено')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для инициализации с клавиатуры:

```
class Test():

    def __init__(self, name=None, geom=None, algebra=None, keyboard = False):

        if keyboard:
            self.name = input('Введите имя: ')
            self.geom = input('Первая оценка: ')
            self.algebra = input('Вторая оценка: ')
        else:
            self.name = name
            self.geom = geom
            self.algebra = algebra

stud3 = Test(keyboard=True)
```

Для обновления оценок (однако не обработана ситуация, когда студент может пока иметь меньше двух оценок, но она и у Вас не обработана):

```
class Test():

    def update(name, geom=None, algebra=None):
        if name in Test.instances:
            student = Test.instances[name]
            student.algebra = algebra or student.algebra
            student.geom = geom or student.geom
            print('Студент {}: {}'.format(name,student))
        else:
            print('Студент не найден')

Test.update("Даша", geom=4)
Test.update("Кристина", algebra=5, geom=5)
```

---

Вот код целиком:

```
class Test():

    stud_count = 0 
    instances = {}

    def __init__(self, name=None, geom=None, algebra=None, keyboard = False):

        if keyboard:
            self.name = input('Введите имя: ')
            self.geom = input('Первая оценка: ')
            self.algebra = input('Вторая оценка: ')
        else:
            self.name = name
            self.geom = geom
            self.algebra = algebra

        Test.instances[self.name] = self
        Test.stud_count += 1
        print('Добавление студента {}'.format(self.name))
        print('Оценки за экзамены - Геометрия:{} ,Алгебра: {}'.format(self.geom, self.algebra)) 

    def search():
        n = input("Введите имя студента: ")
        if n in Test.instances:
            print('Оценки за экзамены: ', Test.instances[n])
        else:
            print('Не найдено')

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Геометрия - {}, Алгебра - {}".format(
            self.geom,
            self.algebra)

    def howMany():
        if Test.stud_count == 0:
            print('В ведомости нет студентов.')
        else:
            print('Всего студентов: %d' % Test.stud_count)   

    def update(name, geom=None, algebra=None):
        if name in Test.instances:
            student = Test.instances[name]
            student.algebra = algebra or student.algebra
            student.geom = geom or student.geom
            print('Студент {}: {}'.format(name,student))
        else:
            print('Студент не найден')

Test.howMany()
stud1 = Test("Даша", 5, 5)

Test.howMany()
stud2 = Test("Кристина", 3, 3)

Test.howMany()
stud3 = Test(keyboard=True)

Test.howMany()

Test.search()

Test.update("Даша", geom=4)
Test.update("Кристина", algebra=5, geom=5)


n = input("Введите имя студента: ")
if n in Test.instances:
     print('Оценки за экзамены: ', Test.instances[n])
else:
     print('Не найдено')
```

Comment: большое спасибо. А как можно удалить определённый экземпляр из словаря?

Comment: `del Test.instances[name]` или `Test.instances.pop(name)`

Comment: Если ответ Вас удовлетворил, то отметьте его, пожалуйста, как принятый.